# Set the maxNumberOfMessages in @SqsListener

Tags: angular, unit-testing, jasmine

I'm quite new in using the `spring-cloud-aws-messaging` in Java Spring.

This is my current AwsConfig

```
    public AmazonSQSAsync amazonSqs(AWSCredentialsProvider awsCredentialsProvider) {
        return AmazonSQSAsyncClientBuilder.standard()
                .withEndpointConfiguration(new AwsClientBuilder.EndpointConfiguration(sqsEndpoint, sqsRegion))
                .withCredentials(awsCredentialsProvider)
                .build();
    }
```

and in a my class Listener, I added an annotation for it to be a `@SqsListener`
May I know where do we set the `maxNumberOfMessages`?

Or it needs to create in the AwsConfig a `SimpleMessageListenerContainerFactory` bean?

I hope to have a friendly answer

Thank you so much for your help :D

Answer (score 0):

- https://github.com/spring-cloud/spring-cloud-aws/issues/387 provides a **SimpleMessageListenerContainer**

```java
        @Override
        public SimpleMessageListenerContainer createSimpleMessageListenerContainer() {
            SimpleMessageListenerContainer simpleMessageListenerContainer = new SimpleMessageListenerContainer() {
                @Override
                protected void startQueue(String queueName, QueueAttributes queueAttributes) {
                    
                    // A place to configure queue based maxNumberOfMessages
                    
                    try {
                        if (queueName.endsWith(".fifo")) {
                            FieldUtils.writeField(queueAttributes, "maxNumberOfMessages", 1, true);
                        }
                    } catch (IllegalAccessException e) {
                        throw new RuntimeException(e);
                    }
                    super.startQueue(queueName, queueAttributes);
                }
            };
            simpleMessageListenerContainer.setAmazonSqs(amazonSqs);
            return simpleMessageListenerContainer;
        }
```

- https://cloud.spring.io/spring-cloud-static/spring-cloud-aws/1.2.3.RELEASE/multi/multi__messaging.html#_the_simplemessagelistenercontainerfactory provides a **SimpleMessageListenerContainerFactory**

```java
@Bean
public SimpleMessageListenerContainerFactory simpleMessageListenerContainerFactory(AmazonSQSAsync amazonSqs) {
    SimpleMessageListenerContainerFactory factory = new SimpleMessageListenerContainerFactory();
    factory.setAmazonSqs(amazonSqs);
    factory.setAutoStartup(false);
    factory.setMaxNumberOfMessages(5);
    // ...

    return factory;
}
```

I'll give the 2nd a try. Haven't tested it yet ...